# How to display a variable number of list items in a accordion list

Tags: react-native, accordion

I am trying to display a variable number of list items inside an accordion list.

Here is the code:

[React-Native Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz31N.png)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { List } from 'react-native-paper';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const data = [
    { bldg: 'Baumer', floors: {floor1: "http://www.google.com", floor2: "http://www.google.com" }},
    { bldg: 'Flanner', floors: {floor1: "http://www.google.com", floor2: "http://www.google.com", floor3: "http://www.google.com" }},
  ];
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(true);

  const handlePress = () => setExpanded(!expanded);

  return (
    <View>
      <List.Section title="Buildings">
        {data.map((bldglist) => (
          <List.Accordion
            title={bldglist.bldg}
            left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon="office-building" />}
            expanded={!expanded}
            onPress={handlePress}>
            <List.Item title={bldglist.floors.floor1} />
          </List.Accordion>
        ))}
      </List.Section>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

The accordion list works but I cannot figure out how to display a variable number of list items.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //iterate through the floors array

{bldglist.floors.map((fl) => (
            <View style={styles.listitem}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', {fl} )}>
                <List.Item
                  title={fl.name}
                  
                  //                onPress={() => Linking.openURL(fl.url)}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).